# How to delete empty rows without having columns values and row values inthe red

Tags: sql, sql-server

Delete Empty Rows

[image]

How to Delete Empty Rows in the table see in the fig

Comment: Actually you just click on the very left of the table form, then the whole row gets marked and then you simply press "del". That should to it.

Comment: Why you have empty rows, isn't CustomerID your primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE CustomerID IS NULL
```

Comment: run these command DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE CustomerID IS NULL but 0 rows effected

Comment: Is CustomerID a text field? If Yes try WHERE CustomerID = ""

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE CustomerID =''
```